# Selenium Timeout Exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the cheapest flight price from  Google Flight search page. 
I got a timeout error, even if I use `WebDriverWait`. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

example_url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=it#flt=/m/07_pf./m/01f62.2019-05-24;c:EUR;e:1;0px:2;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'

def get_price(url):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)
        try:
             wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
             element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price')))
             print(element)
        finally:
             price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price').text
             driver.quit()
        price = float(price.split(' ')[0])
        driver.quit()
        return price       


price = get_price(example_url)
print(price)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semplice.py", line 23, in <module>
    price = get_price(example_url)
  File "semplice.py", line 13, in get_price
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price')))
  File "/home/andrea/ENTER/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

No message has been printed on the terminal. Just this is the message. 
Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it is because you're passing the dot to find the element by class name:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price'))
```

Change it to:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gws-flights-results__cheapest-price')))
```

Answer (score 2):

@kafels is correct, you don't need the dot in front of a classname locator.  However, once you fix that, you don't really need to do the 2nd search in the finally.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

example_url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=it#flt=/m/07_pf./m/01f62.2019-05-24;c:EUR;e:1;0px:2;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'

def get_price(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
                                                             'gws-flights-results__cheapest-price')))
    except Exception as exc:
        raise
    finally:
        # no need to look for the element here since you do it in the try section.
        driver.quit()

    print(element)
    price = element.text
    price = float(price.split(' ')[0])
    return price

price = get_price(example_url)
print(price)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however by using your suggestion I got a connection error "urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f778c7f8a58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
 " .  However if I remove the dot, my code work. Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand... there isn't a dot in my example.